# Combine all rows in a different column that matching email

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am on Windows 10 using the newest version of Excel. I have fairly large dataset. Picture below is a extract of the relevant information. With column A having their email, column B projects they are involved in and column C, the projects they are involved in.

So what I am trying to do is to gather all their projects in one cell, such as C2, and thereafter I can manually delete the rest.

Manually I do this =B2&", "&B3&", "&B4&", "&B5&", "&B6, but since my dataset contains 1200 rows, I am trying to figure out away to not have to do this for each individual.

I am not scared of VBA, but prefer formulas, is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAapD.png)

Comment: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Comment: Hi Scott,

Thank you very much! I am familiar with one-shot go VBA codes, but I have never added UDF. How do I go about to add a general module?

Comment: Just to give you an idea of what I have done..

Insert > Module > pasted your text

Following this I enter the spreadsheet but when I past the code "=IF(MATCH(A1,A:A,0)=ROW(A1),TEXTJOINIFS(B:B,", ",A:A,A1),"") "

It says there is a problem with this function

Comment: Nvm, I did correctly, it's just me who was stupid, I have to use ; instead of ,.

From the bottom of my heart, THANK YOU

For anyone else having the same problem

=IF(MATCH(A1;A:A;0)=ROW(A1);TEXTJOINIFS(B:B;", ";A:A;A1);"")

Answer (score 0):

The folowing simple formula would do:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$1200=A2,$B$2:$B$1200,"")))
```

The outer `IF()` gives the blanks for 2nd through whatever-th instances of the emails. It does so by checking the ever-expanding check range (anchored by absolutely addressed $A$2 expanding to the relatively addressed A2 (so in row 605, the expanding range would be $A$2:A605)) for more than one instance of the column A value and returning a blank if so, or allowing Excel to continue calculation of the cell's formula.

Note that Excel calculates left to right any time such a thing is possible so those cells generating blanks here do not add calculation of the full range (second part of the formula) to the processing burden.

The `TEXTJOIN()` part uses an `IF()` to test each cell in column A matches its own column A cell's value and creates an internal array of the results with FALSE returns entering the array as blanks. The `TEXTJOIN()` itself ignores blanks leaving only the successful matches.

If all you need is to display the results as shown wherever they will occur in those 1200 cells of column C, that all you need.

If you would like the results collected from that column into a "joined-up" batch, you could use the following wherever you wish that batch to be displayed:

```
=UNIQUE(C2:C8,,TRUE)
```

(Using the third parameter with a value of `TRUE` makes sure the blanks don't appear in the list unless there is only a single email that is duplicated a single time.)

It can be sorted with `SORT()`, of course:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(C2:C8,,TRUE))
```

And if, for that output, you'd like to see the email address as well as part of the string, you can change the first formula given above for the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",A2&": "&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$1200=A2,$B$2:$B$1200,"")))
```

in which the `A2&": "&` portion adds in the address to the `TEXTJOIN()` output.

Naturally, once you have that output, you could split those strings as desired. The trick to it is getting the proper column A value to go with each string and that's HARD when just using the "a,b,c,..." output you show in column C as how do you match it up to the proper column A values? But collecting column A's values into the generated strings overcomes that altogether.